# React's Context API re-renders all components that are wrapped inside the Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a very common performance problem while using the Context API. Essentially whenever a state value in the context changes, the entire components that are wrapped between the provider re-renders and causes performance slowdown.

If I have a the wrapper as this:

```
<CounterProvider>
        <SayHello />
        <ShowResult />
        <IncrementCounter />
        <DecrementCounter />
</CounterProvider>
```

And the value props as:

```
<CounterContext.Provider value={{increment, decrement, counter, hello }} >
  {children}
</CounterContext.Provider>
```

Everytime I increment the count value from the `IncrementCounter` component, the entire set of wrapped components re-renders as it is how the Context API is supposed to work.

I did a bit of research and came across these solutions:

1. Split the Context into N number of Context according to the use-case : This solution works as expected.
2. Wrap the value provider using `React.Memo`: I saw a lot of articles suggesting to the React.Memo API as follows:

```
<CounterContext.Provider
  value={useMemo(
    () => ({ increment, decrement, counter, hello }),
    [increment, decrement, counter, hello]
    )}
>
  {children}
</CounterContext.Provider>
```

This however doesn't work as expected. I still can see all the components getting re-rendered. What I'm doing wrong while using the Memo API? [Dan Abramov](https://www.google.com/search?q=dan+abramov&btnK=Google+Search&sxsrf=AOaemvJGuMMi7mvn69OJehyd6B6imlCSNQ%3A1630750900494&source=hp&ei=tEgzYf_nG8Op1sQP_b6uqA4&iflsig=ALs-wAMAAAAAYTNWxAhHEqc3VOiBrLi1JFbQeI5Hpk3q&oq=macos+monterey+update+error&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwghEAoQoAE6BwguECcQkwI6BAgjECc6CAgAELEDEIMBOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToOCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQ0QM6CwguEIAEELEDEIMBOgUIABCABDoFCC4QgAQ6CAgAEIAEELEDOg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARCjAjoLCC4QgAQQxwEQowI6CggAEIAEELEDEAo6BwgAELEDEAo6BAgAEAo6CggAELEDEIMBEAo6BwgAELEDEA06BAgAEA06CAgAEAgQDRAeOgYIABAWEB46BQghEKABOggIIRAWEB0QHlDVBFixVmDnWWgAcAB4AIAB6gOIAZk6kgEKMC4xLjExLjUuNpgBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj_kY7BjOXyAhXDlJUCHX2fC-UQ4dUDCAc&uact=5) does recommend to go by this approach in an open React [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156)

If anyone can help me out on this one. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*"Essentially whenever a state value in the context changes, the entire components that are wrapped between the provider re-renders and causes performance slowdown."*

The above statement is true if a context is used like in the below example where components are directly nested in the provider. All of them re-render when `count` changes, no matter whether they have called `useContext(counterContext)` or not.

```js
const counterContext = React.createContext();
const CounterContextProvider = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <counterContext.Provider value={{ count, setCount }}>
      <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>Change state</button>
      <ComponentOne/>
      <ComponentTwo />
    </counterContext.Provider>
  );
};

const ComponentOne = () => {
  console.log("ComponentOne renders");
  return <div></div>;
};

const ComponentTwo = () => {
  console.log("ComponentTwo renders ");
  return <div></div>;
};
function App() {
  return (
    <CounterContextProvider/>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

*"Essentially whenever a state value in the context changes, the entire components that are wrapped between the provider re-renders and causes performance slowdown."*

The above statement is false if you are consuming nested components with the `children` prop, like in the below example.

This time when `count` changes, `CounterContextProvider` renders, but since it's rendering because its state has changed and not because of its parent rendering, and because a component cannot mutate its `props`, React won't render `children`.

That's it if it was a normal component. But since there is a context involved here, React will find all components that contain `useContext(counterContext)` and render them.

```js
const counterContext = React.createContext();
const CounterContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <counterContext.Provider value={{ count, setCount }}>
      <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>Change state</button>
      {children}
    </counterContext.Provider>
  );
};

const ComponentOne = () => {
  const { count } = React.useContext(counterContext);
  console.log("ComponentOne renders");
  return <div></div>;
};

const ComponentTwo = () => {
  console.log("ComponentTwo renders ");
  return <div></div>;
};
function App() {
  return (
    <CounterContextProvider>
      <ComponentOne />
      <ComponentTwo />
    </CounterContextProvider>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

In the above example only `ComponentOne` renders when `count` changes, which is normal cause he is consuming it. Every component that calls `useContext(counterContext)` renders if one value of the context changes.

Even with `useMemo` wrapping the context `value` object as you did, that's the behavior you get as soon as one variable in its dependency array changes.

If this is bothering you, it's recommended to have multiple simple contexts, instead of one with a `value` object that has multiple key-value pairs.

Comment: *This time when count changes CounterContextProvider renders, but since it's rendering because its state has changed and not because of its parent rendering, and because a component cannot mutate its props, React won't render children. That's it if it was a normal component.* Can you elaborate this? Also link some source if possible

Comment: @TusharShahi I will try to explain with an example - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/white-pine-dzq1nn (couldn't find a direct explanation in the docs) the idea is the same for any component receiving children as props. when you change bg Comp isn't rendered because only App can pass information to Comp (because it creates the Comp instance). The Container receives Comp instance as an immutable object, like any other prop, so when you change bg (state of the Container) there is no need to re-render Comp, nothing could have changed there.

Comment: I think looking at the children props made it more clear to me. I don't know how i missed it. Thanks both