# React Context performance and suggestions

Tags: reactjs, react-context

This is a phrase you can find in many sites and it is considered (?) as valid:

> React Context is often used to avoid prop drilling, however it's known
> that there's a performance issue. When a context value is changed, all components
> that use `useContext` will re-render.

Moreover:

> The React team has proposed a `useSelectedContext` hook to prevent performance issues
> with Context at scale. There is a community library for that: [use-context-selector](https://github.com/dai-shi/use-context-selector)

However, for me the above does not make any sense. Don't we want to re-render all the components that use `useContext`? Absolutely! Once the context value changes, all components using it must re-render. Otherwise, UI won't be in sync with the state. So, ***what exactly is the performance issue***?

We could discuss how not to re-render the other child components of the Context Provider that do not use `useContext` and this is achievable ([react docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/scaling-up-with-reducer-and-context#moving-all-wiring-into-a-single-file)):

```
<TasksContext.Provider value={tasks}>
  <TasksDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
    {children}
  </TasksDispatchContext.Provider>
</TasksContext.Provider>
```

By using the above pattern, we can avoid re-rendering of all child components that do not use `useContext`.

***To recap: In my opinion, there is no performance issue when using Context the right way. The only components that will re-render are the ones that should re-render. However, almost all references insist on an underlying performance issue and stress that as one of Context's caveats. Am I missing something?***

Comment: Is it not the difference between re-rendering on a context slice vs "the context"? E.g., it's closer to a prop/state change re-render because you can specify what part of the context actually matters to a component.

Comment: see [this](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2021/01/context-redux-differences/)

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed How does that address the question?

Comment: @Dave Newton I have nothing understood from what you said.

Comment: This thread discusses the same thing in certain ways: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73599444/reacts-context-api-re-renders-all-components-that-are-wrapped-inside-the-contex

Comment: The problem is not with Context but with how it is (ab)used. Just read the caveats: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats

Answer (score 13):

Note: I'll answer your questions and give a final comment on what I could gather on the internet and from personal experience.

**TL;DR**: The performance issue is a constant reminder that when you use `Context API` even if not explicitly writing it **you are virtually passing those props** to the components that use a Context State and on **each state change** for every component that state is accessed, **those components will be re-rendered**.

Answering each question from your post:

> Question 1: Don't we want to re-render all the components that use `useContext`?

Yes, that's exactly it, as you stated.

> Question 2: So, ***what exactly is the performance issue***?

On **prop changes, components re-render**. When using `Context API`, even if not explicitly passing the Context state as a prop, each state change will trigger a re-render on that component and the child components that depend on or receive that state as a prop. [You can read this on this doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) such as:

> *Context provides a way to share values like these between components without having to explicitly pass a prop through every level of the tree*

This is not exactly an issue as the docs suggest you use it to store **global state** that does not change that much such as:

- Theme
- Authentication/Login state
- Language/i18n

Those are the type of data that:

- if changed, should trigger a "global" re-render as it'll affect the App, as a whole
- do not change that much (or do not change at all) on each App interaction
- will be used on different nesting levels

> Question 3: Am I missing something?

Well, as you could already suppose, there are a lot of cases that don't match that type of usage of a "global state" that doesn't change that much. And, for those, there are some other options that could be used to take care of the same set of cases that `Context API` solve, but with a lot more overhead at the code. One of them is `Redux`, which doesn't have this overhead for the most obvious reason: `Redux` creates a parallel `store` from your App and doesn't pass the values as props to each and every component. On the other hand, one of the most noticeable overheads is the tooling that the project should have to accommodate that library.

*But why people started using `Redux`(and other libs) in the first place?*

Handling Global State in past versions of `React` was a thing. You could solve this with a lot of different ways, opinions, and approaches. Sooner or later, people started to create and use tools and libs that handles that with approaches that were considered "better" for specific or personal reasons.

Later, those tools/libs started to get more complex and with more possible "connectors" or "middlewares" here and there. As an example, one tool that can be added to `Redux` to handle requests is the lib called [`Redux Thunk`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), which allows performing requests inside actions (if I'm not wrong) breaking the concept of just writing actions as **pure functions** from `Redux`. Nowadays, with the growth of [`React Query`](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/)/[`TanStack Query`](https://tanstack.com/query/latest), the state related to the requests is starting to be handled also as a parallel "global state" even with cache and a lot more features, dropping the usage of `Redux Thunk` and `Redux` as a consequence to solve the "global state" from requests.

After [the release of `Context API` to a stable and improved version](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html), people started to use it for a lot of projects and **as a Global State manager**. And sooner or later everyone started to notice performance issues related to too many re-renders due to several props changing every time, everywhere. Some of them just went back to the `Redux` and other libs but for others, turns out that `Context API` is very good, practical, involves less overhead, and is embedded with `React` if used as it was intended. The requirements for not having to deal with the performance issues are the same as described before:

- a global state that does not change so frequently and
- will be used on different nesting levels

There are some other options that `Context API` works smoothly if you don't nest too many components. As an example: Multi-page Forms if you create the context at the `Route` level and not at the `App` level. As you also stated:

> *In my opinion, there is no performance issue when using Context the right way*

But you could say that for almost every tool that is used out of its original usage conception.

---

Edit: After the OP pointed out and after reading about the Context API in the official docs, **props are not passed to each and every child**, just for those who use the context. And as a consequence: To each and every child component for those components that pass those props to them.

And, answering the question on **why `Context API` has performance issues**, I'm planning to create a repo to reproduce and understand but **my bet** is: It is probably related to the fact that each `Context` is called as "component" and React handles that itself, instead of creating a "parallel structure" such as `Redux`/`Jotai`, as an example.

Comment: I think your understanding about how React Context works is not right! You mentioned that `When using Context API, even if not explicit, each prop is passed from parent to child on every component.`  and this is completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I made some changes and added a final section describing a possible cause.

Answer (score 6):

> To recap: In my opinion, there is no performance issue when using Context the right way. The only components that will re-render are the ones that should re-render.

If your Provider only provides a simple value, your recap is true.

But in reality the Provider often provides a big tree object containing many branches and leaves. However each Consumer may only need a small portion of it, even a single leaf value on that tree.

In this case there is a perf problem, cus the Context API is a whole sale solution. Even if you update a single leaf value, you still need to update the tree root object’s reference in order to signal a change. But that in turn notifies **every single Consumer** that `useContext`.

#### Now here’s the point that you’re missing:

It’s true that every one of them should be **notified** of a change, but it’s not true that all of them should **re-render**. Optimally only those Consumer which depend on the updated leaf value should re-render.

At its current state Context API doesn’t provide any fine grained control over this issue, thus things like `use-context-selector` bring back the selector pattern back into our sight.

---

Fundamentally this is a pub-sub model, and if you don’t have a mechanism to allow subs to decide which channel to tune in, the only thing you can do is to broadcast to all subs about everything. It’s like waking everybody in the neighborhood up just to tell them “Alice got a new mail”, which obviously is not optimal.

The very same problem exists in barebone Redux setup. Which is why selector pattern from `react-redux` used to be very popular.

Comment: Could have just linked to https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats.

Comment: I just read it, yet it isn’t obvious how that doc relates to OP’s question about perf issue. Maybe it’s obvious to you, but I believe an explainer is still useful.

Comment: I think what you refer to can be easily solved by creating many contexts. It is not considered as good practice to pass objects as Provider values.

Comment: You asked where is the perf issue cus you didn’t see one. I said there is one when you pass complex object. I didn’t say what is right or wrong way to use Context API. I was merely answering your question.

Comment: And yes, it’s could be solved by using many contexts, but this approach is tedious. As of “not considered as good practice to pass objects”, what is your argument? Because good or bad, it’s definitely a **common** practice AFAICT, and precisely the reason why lib like `use-context-selector` exists.

Comment: This is also solved with MobX, where you don't need to change the root of a context in order to trigger renders, and only components that access a specific leaf will be updated at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 3):

There is no performance issue with contextAPI if you read the docs thoroughly :)

The problems begin when people use the context API as s store for multiple values, and not all components need all the values.

Generally react looks at the context value as a single value, and it is immutable (otherwise nothing will work), so all components using the context will re-render when anything changes in the context value, even if they don't use the piece of information that changed.

Having said that, you don't have to use Redux or any other global state management library each time you have a slightly more complicated local(ish) state (if you have a real local state - put the state in the component).

You can build a small external store of your own, and expose only an API on the context - the API never changes. [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/throbbing-moon-uvbor3?file=%2FREADME.md) is an example of how to do that.

I can't put all the code inline.. but

this could be the store, there are many other options, of course, the important part is the use of `useSyncExternalStore` which connects our external store to the react life cycle.

```
import { set, unset, get, PropertyPath } from "lodash";
import { useSyncExternalStore } from "react";

export type SimpleReactiveStore = ReturnType<typeof createSimpleReactiveStore>;
/**
 *
 * @returns a simple store you can use with your react components.
 */
export function createSimpleReactiveStore() {
  const data: object = {};
  const registry: ((data: object) => void)[] = [];

  function subscribe(listener: (data: object) => void) {
    registry.push(listener);
    return () => {
      registry.splice(registry.indexOf(listener), 1);
    };
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param path
   * @param value has to be an immutable value if you want it to trigger a re-render.
   */
  function setValue<T>(path: PropertyPath, value: T) {
    if (value === undefined) {
      unset(data, path);
    } else {
      set(data, path, value);
    }

    registry.forEach((li) => li(data));
  }

  function getValue<T>(path: PropertyPath) {
    return get(data, path) as T;
  }

  function useValue<T>(path: PropertyPath, defaultValue: T) {
    const value = useSyncExternalStore(
      subscribe,
      () => getValue<T>(path) || defaultValue
    );
    return value;
  }

  return {
    useValue,
    setValue,
    getValue,
  };
}
```

and this could the hook exposing the API, you can use it in a context provider or any other component

```
function useTodos() {
  const store = useRef(createSimpleReactiveStore());

  const api = useMemo(
    () => ({
      addTodo: (todo: Todo) => {
        const list = store.current.getValue<string[]>(TODO_LIST_PATH) || [];
        //we store the ids in an array so that they will have a particular order
        store.current.setValue(TODO_LIST_PATH, [...list, todo.id]);
        store.current.setValue(todo.id, todo);
      },
      setTodo: (todo: Todo) => store.current.setValue(todo.id, todo),
      useTodo: (id: string) =>
        store.current.useValue<Todo | undefined>(id, undefined),
      useTodoList: () => store.current.useValue<string[]>(TODO_LIST_PATH, []),
    }),
    []
  );

  return api;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a library just to use Context in an optimal and easy way. Its name is [react-context-slices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-slices). It allows you to define slices of Context easily and fetch them using a single hook, `useSlice`. It's something like this:

```
// slices.js
import getHookAndProviderFromSlices from "react-context-slices"
export const {useSlice, Provider} = getHookAndProviderFromSlices({
  count: {initialArg: 0},
  // rest of slices of Context you want to define
})
```

```
// app.js
import {useSlice} from "./slices"
const App = () => {
  const [count, useCount] = useSlice("count")
  return <>
    <button onClick={() => setCount(c => c + 1)}>+</button>{count}
  </>
}
```

As you can see it's easy to use and fast. If you see the performance of the app is compromised, it's a sign you defined a slice with too much unrelated information in it and you have to break it down into more slices.

So I agree with you that Context API if used correctly does not compromise performance (as far as I know). This library reduces the amount of boilerplate to use Context API to 0. You just have to define the slices of Context with four optional arguments: `initialArg`, `reducer`, `init`, and `isGetInitialStateFromStorage`. The first three are the same that React documentation specifies for the `useReducer` hook. So check there the info to know what they do, if you need it. The fourth as its name specify serves the purpose of reading or recovering the initial state of a slice from local storage (for web) or AsyncStorage (for React Native).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are basically correct, but slightly misleading. It's important to clarify the difference between a **re-render** and a **re-evaluation**. If you have a state tree in a context, every component that uses that context will **re-evaluate** every time the context object changes, but it will only **re-render** if the JSX returned from the component has changed since the last render. Re-evaluation is generally not expensive as long as you are memoizing any complex data transformations that run inside the component body.

Given the following app:

```
const Context = React.createContext<{ foo: string; bar: string }>({ foo: '', bar: '' })

function Foo() {
  const { foo } = React.useContext(Context);
  console.log('rendering Foo');
  return <h1>{foo}</h1>;
}

function Bar() {
  const { bar } = React.useContext(Context);
  console.log('rendering Bar');
  return <h2>{bar}</h2>;
}

function App() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState('foo');
  const [bar, setBar] = React.useState('bar');
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ foo, bar }}>
      <div className="App">
        <Foo />
        <Bar />
      </div>
      <input value={foo} onChange={e => setFoo(e.target.value)} />
      <input value={bar} onChange={e => setBar(e.target.value)} />
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

If the user updates the value of the `foo` input, the console will log

```
rendering Foo
rendering Bar
```

on every keypress. However, if you turn on paint flashing in the dev tools Rendering panel, you'll only see the `Foo` component flash. You'd need to have a very large and complex component tree to start noticing any slowdowns related to component re-evaluation, but it's definitely something to keep an eye on in a customer facing commercial application. As with most things react, you should be keeping an eye on your FPS in browser dev tools, using CPU throttling to simulate low power devices, and optimizing for performance when and only when you have screen updates that take longer than ~20ms regularly. In practice, your bloated UI framework, CSS-in-JS library, and massively redundant graphql requests are far more likely to cause performance issues than keeping your global state tree in context.

Comment: You’re right. But I do want to clarify, in the context of react discussion, what you call “re-evaluation” is often called “re-render”.

Comment: Yea, and I think by re-render he means reconciliation. Re-render is generally inexpensive, reconciliation is when the actual DOM is updated, and that can be expensive.